# Socket.io - Why are volatile messages rapidly sent by the server not being received by the client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

When firing off multiple emits from the server, I am getting a behavior I was not expecting for `volatile` messages.

When I do a regular `emit` in rapid succession via a loop, all messages are received by the client and can be inspected via chrome network inspector.  When I change to doing `volatile.emit`, I am only receiving the first message (of 100).

The question is, why is this the case?

From my understanding of:
https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-volatile-messages , I would expect all of the messages to be sent, even if they are not received by the client.  If they are indeed being sent, then why is `emit` able to be received for all messages, while `volatile.emit` is not?

Below is a link to a repo that is a setup of my test between volatile and non volatile messages.
https://github.com/GStipick/socketioVolatileTest

Additionally, I noticed that if I had a 50ms delay to sending each `volatile.emit` message via `setTimeout()` then all messages are sent correctly (but of course with a delay).  What factors go into this method working as expected, but not immediate `volatile.emit`s working like regular `emit`s?

Comment: did you find why?

Comment: No.  I still have not found out why.  My question on their github page has not had any response either.  If you want to give that thread some attention, that would be great.  https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3350

Answer (score 1):

See this explanation of one of developers

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/115#issuecomment-317647596

```js
if (opts.volatile && !self.conn.transport.writable) return;
```

> This means that when the server is going to send a message, if it finds that the output buffer for the socket is full, instead of blocking and wait for the buffer to have space it just throws away the message.

So `volatile` are not like "fire and forget" they are more like "fire if you are not busy right now".

Server uses `ws` library to work with WebSockets.

It sets `writable` to `false` and then calls `send`:

```js
      this.writable = false;

      this.socket.send(data, opts, err => {
        if (err) return this.onError("write error", err.stack);
        this.send(packets);
      });
```

`writable` changes to `true` when all packets are sent:

```js
    const packet = packets.shift();
    if (typeof packet === "undefined") {
      this.writable = true;
```

So the first volatile packet will be sent, but while any packets are sending, new volatile packets are completely ignored. This explains why if you add a time delay between volatile packets, they have a higher probability of being sent. However if one tries to send a burst of volatile packets, almost all of them can be discarded.